# Relating column names to model parameters in pySpark ML

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I'm running a model using GLM (using ML in Spark 2.0) on data that has one categorical independent variable.  I'm converting that column into dummy variables using `StringIndexer` and `OneHotEncoder`, then using `VectorAssembler` to combine it with a continuous independent variable into a column of sparse vectors.

If my column names are `continuous` and `categorical` where the first is a column of floats and the second is a column of strings denoting (in this case, 8) different categories:

```
string_indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol='categorical', 
                               outputCol='categorical_index')

encoder = OneHotEncoder(inputCol ='categorical_index',
                        outputCol='categorical_vector')

assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['continuous', 'categorical_vector'],
                            outputCol='indep_vars')

pipeline  = Pipeline(stages=string_indexer+encoder+assembler)
model = pipeline.fit(df)
df = model.transform(df)
```

Everything works fine to this point, and I run the model:

```
glm = GeneralizedLinearRegression(family='gaussian', 
                                  link='identity',
                                  labelCol='dep_var',
                                  featuresCol='indep_vars')
model = glm.fit(df)
model.params
```

Which outputs:

> DenseVector([8440.0573, 3729.449, 4388.9042, 2879.1802, 4613.7646, 5163.3233, 5186.6189, 5513.1392])

Which is great, because I can verify that these coefficients are essentially correct (via other sources).  However, I haven't found a good way to **link these coefficients to the original column names**, which I need to do (I've simplified this model for SO; there's more involved.)

The relationship between column names and coefficients is broken by `StringIndexer` and `OneHotEncoder`.  I've found one fairly slow way:

```
df[['categorical', 'categorical_index']].distinct()
```

Which gives me a small dataframe relating the the string names to the numerical names, which I think I could then relate back to the keys in the sparse vector?  This is very clunky and slow though, when you consider the scale of the data.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

For PySpark, here is the solution to map feature index to feature name:

First, train your model:

```
pipeline = Pipeline().setStages([label_stringIdx,assembler,classifier])
model = pipeline.fit(x)
```

Transform your data:

```
df_output = model.transform(x)
```

Extract the mapping between feature index and feature name. Merge numeric attributes and binary attributes into a single list.

```
numeric_metadata = df_output.select("features").schema[0].metadata.get('ml_attr').get('attrs').get('numeric')
binary_metadata = df_output.select("features").schema[0].metadata.get('ml_attr').get('attrs').get('binary')

merge_list = numeric_metadata + binary_metadata
```

OUTPUT:

```
[{'name': 'variable_abc', 'idx': 0},
{'name': 'variable_azz', 'idx': 1},
{'name': 'variable_azze', 'idx': 2},
{'name': 'variable_azqs', 'idx': 3},
  ....
```

Answer (score 4):

I also came across the exact problem and I've got your solution :)

This is based on the Scala version here:
[How to map variable names to features after pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36122559/how-to-map-variable-names-to-features-after-pipeline)

```
# transform data
best_model = pipeline.fit(df)
best_pred = best_model.transform(df)

# extract features metadata
meta = [f.metadata 
    for f in best_pred.schema.fields 
    if f.name == 'features'][0]

# access feature name and index
features_name_ind = meta['ml_attr']['attrs']['numeric'] + \
    meta['ml_attr']['attrs']['binary']

print features_name_ind[:2]
# [{'name': 'feature_name_1', 'idx': 0}, {'name': 'feature_name_2', 'idx': 1}]
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't investigate the previous versions, but in Spark 2.4.3 it is possible to retrieve a lot of information about the features just by using the `summary` attribute of a `GeneralizedLinearRegressionModel`.

Printing `summary` results in something like this:

```
Coefficients:
            Feature Estimate Std Error T Value P Value
        (Intercept)  -0.1742    0.4298 -0.4053  0.6853
  x1_enc_(-inf,5.5]  -0.7781    0.3661 -2.1256  0.0335
   x1_enc_(5.5,8.5]   0.1850    0.3736  0.4953  0.6204
   x1_enc_(8.5,9.5]  -0.3937    0.4324 -0.9106  0.3625
 x45_enc_1-10-7-8-9  -0.5382    0.2718 -1.9801  0.0477
   x45_enc_2-3-4-ND   0.5187    0.2811  1.8454  0.0650
          x45_enc_5  -0.0456    0.3353 -0.1361  0.8917
          x33_enc_1   0.6361    0.4043  1.5731  0.1157
         x33_enc_10   0.0059    0.4083  0.0145  0.9884
 x33_enc_2-3-4-8-ND   0.6121    0.1741  3.5152  0.0004
x102_enc_(-inf,4.5]   0.5315    0.1695  3.1354  0.0017

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1.0000)
    Null deviance: 937.7397 on 666 degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 858.8846 on 666 degrees of freedom
AIC: 880.8846
```

The `Feature` column can be constructed by accessing an internal Java object:

```
In [131]: glm.summary._call_java('featureNames')
Out[131]:
['x1_enc_(-inf,5.5]',
 'x1_enc_(5.5,8.5]',
 'x1_enc_(8.5,9.5]',
 'x45_enc_1-10-7-8-9',
 'x45_enc_2-3-4-ND',
 'x45_enc_5',
 'x33_enc_1',
 'x33_enc_10',
 'x33_enc_2-3-4-8-ND',
 'x102_enc_(-inf,4.5]']
```

The `Estimate` column can be constructed by the following concatenation:

```
In [134]: [glm.intercept] + list(glm.coefficients)
Out[134]:
[-0.17419580191414719,
 -0.7781490190325139,
 0.1850214800764976,
 -0.3936963366945294,
 -0.5382255101657534,
 0.5187453074755956,
 -0.045649677050663987,
 0.6360647167539958,
 0.00593020879299306,
 0.6121475986933201,
 0.531510974697773]
```

PS.: [This line](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.3/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/regression/GeneralizedLinearRegression.scala#L1219) shows why the column `Features` can be retrieved by using an internal Java object.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this seems to be a very late answer and maybe you might have already figured it out but wth, anyways. I recently did the same implementation of String Indexer, OneHotEncoder and VectorAssembler and as far as I have understood, the following code will present what you are looking for.

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.feature import OneHotEncoder, StringIndexer, VectorAssembler

categoricalColumns = ["one_categorical_variable"]
stages = [] # stages in the pipeline


for categoricalCol in categoricalColumns:

# Category Indexing with StringIndexer
stringIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol=categoricalCol, 
    outputCol=categoricalCol+"Index")

# Using OneHotEncoder to convert categorical variables into binary 
    SparseVectors

encoder = OneHotEncoder(inputCol=stringIndexer.getOutputCol(), 
    outputCol=categoricalCol+"classVec")

# Adding the stages so that they will be run all at once later

stages += [stringIndexer, encoder]

# convert label into label indices using the StringIndexer

label_stringIdx = StringIndexer(inputCol = "Service_Level", outputCol = 
    "label")
stages += [label_stringIdx]

# Transform all features into a vector using VectorAssembler

numericCols = ["continuous_variable"]
assemblerInputs = map(lambda c: c + "classVec", categoricalColumns) + 
    numericCols
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=assemblerInputs, outputCol="features")
stages += [assembler]

# Creating a Pipeline for Training

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=stages)

# Running the feature transformations.
pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(df)
df = pipelineModel.transform(df)
```

Comment: well the thing is when you see a entry in the 'feature' column in the df (the one in the last row) how are you going to tie it back to the original feature name? (