# Pyspark random forest feature importance mapping after column transformations

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to plot the feature importances of certain tree based models with column names. I am using Pyspark.

Since I had textual categorical variables and numeric ones too, I had to use a pipeline method which is something like this -

1. use string indexer to index string columns
2. use one hot encoder for all columns
3. use a vectorassembler to create the feature column containing the feature vector

   Some sample code from the [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/mllib/binary-classification-mllib-pipelines.html) for steps 1,2,3 -

   ```
   from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
   from pyspark.ml.feature import OneHotEncoderEstimator, StringIndexer, 
   VectorAssembler
   categoricalColumns = ["workclass", "education", "marital_status", 
   "occupation", "relationship", "race", "sex", "native_country"]
    stages = [] # stages in our Pipeline
    for categoricalCol in categoricalColumns:
       # Category Indexing with StringIndexer
       stringIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol=categoricalCol, 
       outputCol=categoricalCol + "Index")
       # Use OneHotEncoder to convert categorical variables into binary 
       SparseVectors
       # encoder = OneHotEncoderEstimator(inputCol=categoricalCol + "Index", 
       outputCol=categoricalCol + "classVec")
       encoder = OneHotEncoderEstimator(inputCols= 
       [stringIndexer.getOutputCol()], outputCols=[categoricalCol + "classVec"])
       # Add stages.  These are not run here, but will run all at once later on.
       stages += [stringIndexer, encoder]

   numericCols = ["age", "fnlwgt", "education_num", "capital_gain", 
   "capital_loss", "hours_per_week"]
   assemblerInputs = [c + "classVec" for c in categoricalColumns] + numericCols
   assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=assemblerInputs, outputCol="features")
   stages += [assembler]

   # Create a Pipeline.
   pipeline = Pipeline(stages=stages)
   # Run the feature transformations.
   #  - fit() computes feature statistics as needed.
   #  - transform() actually transforms the features.
   pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(dataset)
   dataset = pipelineModel.transform(dataset)
   ```
4. finally train the model

   after training and eval, I can use the "model.featureImportances" to get the feature rankings, however I dont get the feature/column names, rather just the feature number, something like this -

   ```
   print dtModel_1.featureImportances

   (38895,[38708,38714,38719,38720,38737,38870,38894],[0.0742343395738,0.169404823667,0.100485791055,0.0105823115814,0.0134236162982,0.194124862158,0.437744255667])
   ```

How do I map it back to the initial column names and the values? So that I can plot ?**

Answer (score 13):

Extract metadata as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42959818/9964676) by [user6910411](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6910411/user6910411)

```py
attrs = sorted(
    (attr["idx"], attr["name"])
    for attr in (
        chain(*dataset.schema["features"].metadata["ml_attr"]["attrs"].values())
    )
)
```

and combine with feature importance:

```py
[
    (name, dtModel_1.featureImportances[idx])
    for idx, name in attrs
    if dtModel_1.featureImportances[idx]
]
```

Comment: Yes, I was actually able to figure it out. 

I did it slightly differently, I created a pandas dataframe with the idx and feature names and then converted to a dictionary which was broadcast variable.

`code`

Comment: `pandasDF = pd.DataFrame(dataset.schema["features"].metadata["ml_attr"]["attrs"]["binary"]+dataset.schema["features"].metadata["ml_attr"]["attrs"]["numeric"]).sort_values("idx")

feature_dict = dict(zip(pandasDF["idx"],pandasDF["name"]))

feature_dict_broad = sc.broadcast(feature_dict)`

Answer (score 3):

The transformed dataset metdata has the required attributes.Here is an easy way to do -

1. create a pandas dataframe (generally feature list will not be huge, so no memory issues in storing a pandas DF)

   ```
   pandasDF = pd.DataFrame(dataset.schema["features"].metadata["ml_attr"] 
   ["attrs"]["binary"]+dataset.schema["features"].metadata["ml_attr"]["attrs"]["numeric"]).sort_values("idx")
   ```
2. Then create a broadcast dictionary to map. broadcast is necessary in a distributed environment.

   ```
   feature_dict = dict(zip(pandasDF["idx"],pandasDF["name"])) 

   feature_dict_broad = sc.broadcast(feature_dict)
   ```

Comment: When I do this, it doesn't show my numeric column names, it just says "numeric_feature_1", "numeric_feature_2" ... I have a few transformations that I do to my numeric variables. Would this make them disappear?

Answer (score 2):

When creating your assembler you used a list of variables (assemblerInputs). The order is preserved in 'features' variable. So just do a Pandas DataFrame:

```
features_imp_pd = (
     pd.DataFrame(
       dtModel_1.featureImportances.toArray(), 
       index=assemblerInputs, 
       columns=['importance'])
)
```